# garbled css name when styling within UiBinder

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder

For my GWT application, I want to show the selected row in a FlexTable, and for that purpose I add a style to the specific row:

```
@UiField FlexTable productTable;
int row;
[...]
/* select row */
productTable.getRowFormatter().addStyleName(row, "row-selected");
```

In the corresponding ui.xml file, I have the style added as follows:

```
ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
xmlns:u="urn:import:myapplication.client.ui">
<ui:style>
    tr.row-selected {
        background: #92C1F0;
    }
</ui:style>
<g:VerticalPanel>
    <g:ScrollPanel>
        <g:FlexTable ui:field="productTable" width="100%" height="100%">
        </g:FlexTable>
    </g:ScrollPanel>
</g:VerticalPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

This does not work, while adding the style in my global .css file does. In FireBug I see that the name **tr.row-selected** is garbled into something like: **tr.GB1HWLGEI**

Why does this not work and how should it work instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UiBinder [uses `ClientBundle` for `ui:style`](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Hello_Stylish_World), so the rules and syntax/features of `CssResource` apply.

This means that your CSS class names will be obfuscated (so that they're unique and won't conflict with a same-named CSS class from another `CssResource` or external stylesheet).

In your case, you can either define a `CssResource` interface and declare the `ui:style` to extend that interface and inject the instance into a `@UiField`; so you can use the obfuscated style into your `addStyleName`; as in http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Programmatic_access
Or you can use `@external` in your `ui:style` to disable obfuscation for the CSS class; see http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#External_and_legacy_scopes.

Comment: Thank you, I'll use the @external because I don't need programmatic access to the styles, and using it is the simplest way to have my style defined in the .ui.xml file.

Comment: Well, `productTable.getRowFormatter().addStyleName(row, "row-selected");` to me implies "programmatic access": add `@UiField MyStyle style;` and then `productTable.getRowFormatter().addStyleName(row, style.rowSelected());` and you benefit from the guaranteed uniqueness of the obfuscated CSS class name.

Answer (score 2):

Garbled is really obfuscated which will be faster in the browser and harder for someone to reverse engineer. It also means you don't need to worry about css namespace conflicts.

So, just use the following line in your ModuleName.gwt.xml file during development to disable obfuscation.

```
<set-configuration-property name="CssResource.style" value="pretty" />
```

Comment: It is set-configuration-property, not extend-... : CssResource.style is not multi-valued, so it cannot be extended.

Comment: My mistake. Corrected. Thx Alex.